# Retrieve and XML element and store as a variable

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm attempting to read an XML file for .
XML document:
    
    /stagingform

My code returns a null for $dir can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("configfile.xml"));
$dir = $xml->codedir;
echo "* * * * directory * * ** -> ".$dir;
```

I can see the contents of configfile.xml with:

```
echo htmlentities($xml->asXML());
```

But I'm unable to set $dir to /stagingform.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the xml file, or the relevant parts of it?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("configfile.xml"));
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    if($child->getName()=="codedir"){
        echo $child;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier function to use would be `simplexml_load_file`, used like so (Supports remote/local files):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/");

print_r($xml);
```